# Display posts on parent post if author coincides

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, author

On a website, I have 4 *article authors*. I want to display each author's posts on his own *custom post page*.

I have come up with this piece of code:

```
<ul class="author-posts">
  <?php $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=7&posts_per_page=30&order=DESC&author_name=john' );
    while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
   ?>
    <li class="author-post"><?php the_content();?></li>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

The problem with the code above is that only one author's name is **john**.

So the WP_Query does not display **terry's** posts.

If every parent page (actually, a *custom post*) has an author, how do I store the parent page's author in a variable so that I can show on it only the posts belonging to the *current author*?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it (easy one):

In functions.php:

```
// Allow author for custom post
function allowShowAuthor()
{
  add_post_type_support( 'cust_post-type', 'author' );
}

add_action('init','allowShowAuthor');
```

In the content *template*:

```
<ul class="author-posts">
 <?php
        $current_page_author = get_the_author();
        $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=7&posts_per_page=30&order=DESC&author_name=' . $current_page_author );
    while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
   ?>
    <li class="author-post"><?php the_content();?></li>
<?php endwhile;?>
```